# Kinect RGBDemo v0.6.1 in QTcreator

Tags: opencv, qt-creator, kinect, osx-lion

I would like to get this [demo](http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectUseNestk#tocLink13) running in my QTcreator. I' running this on osx 10.7 and i have the latest opencv installed. I can run this demo outside the qt creator but that's all. I was wondering how to make this work as a QTcreator project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by opening the cmake file in qtcreator it will then load all the files an can be compiled .